# Fetch products with 5 star reviews

Tags: product, magento-2.1, ratings, product-review

I'm trying to fetch all the products which are having 5 star rating on home page.

Used objectManager for product collection.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
}
```

Not finding any solution in Magento 2.

Thanks you

Comment: First, using objectManager  is not good practice. And do you want only products of home-page ?

Comment: not exactly of home-page products, i have to put slider over there, if it is static collection then also it would be fine

Comment: ok.that means you want to put all 5-start-reviewed products on home-page.

Comment: very true, kind of widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

And then:

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollection->addAttributeToSelect("*")->joinField('rating_score',
    'review_entity_summary',
    'rating_summary',
    'entity_pk_value=entity_id',
    array('entity_type'=>1, 'store_id'=> $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(), 'rating_summary'=> 100),
    'right'
);

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getSku().' '.$product->getName().'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: this works for me @Sohel, rating_summary 100 like it